# Is there a simple way to sum a row of cells that have leading text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 cells - they contain these 3 values beginning with 'x' with a sum of 15 that I have input manually for now.

[image: X1 | X4 | X10]

Is there an easy way to sum the 1+4+10 to get the 15, in the 4th column?

I can cut the x off the beginning with this formula:
[image]

**How do I cut all the x's off A1:C1, and sum the values in cell D1? I can only use cell D1 for my total.**
I have tried this:
[image]

Note: The leading text is always the same!
Note: This is just a minimal reproducible example. My real data has 100 columns.

Many thanks

UPDATE:

here is a snip of the answer! not: all cells in range must be populated or will return an error.
[image]

Comment: Yes, there are multiple rather easy formulas to do this. Try research `MID()` or `SUBSTITUTE()`, `SUM()` and alike. If the leading text is not always the same you could use other methods. Please provide a [mcve] and update your question with your own attempt at solving your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have added more information.

Comment: So just use your right() formula on the 3 cells and sum. like this: RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)+RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-1)

Comment: Please see amended question. I have tried to encase the formula in sum(). What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Hi, thanks mike. This is just a minimal reproducible example. My real data has 100 columns. I'm going to be here for a long time.

Comment: @Becca just seen your latest edit to your question and have posted an update to my solution, do have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the following:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)+RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-1)
```

Or:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","")+SUBSTITUTE(B1,"x","")+SUBSTITUTE(C1,"x","")
```

Edit: JvdV has a really good suggestion of:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:C1,"x",""))
```

which sorts the OP's issue neatly.

To deal with empty cells, try the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:D1,"x",""),0))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks mike. This is just a minimal reproducible example. My real data has 100 columns. I'm going to be here for a long time.

Comment: Or just `=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:C1,"x",""))`

Comment: @Becca then if the "x" is not needed for other things, I would select the complete sheet and do a find & replace and replace the "X" with "".

Comment: The x is needed unfortunately.

Comment: @JvdV if you post your own answer then I will remove your suggestion from mine.

Comment: Not needed, keep everything in a single post =)

Comment: the sumproduct is the answer! thank you very much both!

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the leading text is fixed (1 in this case):

=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(A1:C1,LEN(A1:C1)-1)))

then hit Ctrl Shift Enter instead of Enter

Answer (score 0):

Bit late in response, you may try the one as mentioned below as well

```
=SUM(IFERROR(REPLACE(A1:C1,1,1,"")/1,0))
```